# How to update two field based on the return Json

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I have the folliwng script which actually make two calls to two seperate action methods, and update the related fields:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Switch_RackID").change(function () {
            var idRack = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON("/Switch/LoadDataCenterByRack", { id: idRack },
            function (RackData) {
                var select = $("#Switch_TMSRack_DataCenter_Name");
                select.empty();
                $("#Switch_TMSRack_DataCenter_Name").val(RackData.Text);

            });
            $.getJSON("/Switch/LoadZoneByRack", { id: idRack },
            function (RackData2) {
                var select = $("#Switch_TMSRack_Zone_Name");
                select.empty();
                $("#Switch_TMSRack_Zone_Name").val(RackData2.Text);

            });
            });
        });



</script>
```

But my question is weather I can make a single call using getjson instead of doing two calls, and then update the related fields ? my action methods look as follow:-

```
      public JsonResult LoadDataCenterByRack(int id)
            {
                string datacentername = repository.FindRack(id).DataCenter.Name;

                var DCData = new { Text = datacentername, Value = datacentername };

                return Json(DCData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
public JsonResult LoadZoneByRack(int id)
            {
                string zonername = repository.FindRack(id).Zone.Name;

                var ZData = new { Text = zonername, Value = zonername };

                return Json(ZData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Can anyone advice please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. You can return `Anonymous object`

Change your controller action as

```
public JsonResult LoadDataCenterByRack(int id)
{
    string datacentername = repository.FindRack(id).DataCenter.Name;
    var DCData = new { Text = datacentername, Value = datacentername };

    string zonername = repository.FindRack(id).Zone.Name;
    var ZData = new { Text = zonername, Value = zonername };

    return Json(new {
        DCData,
        ZData
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

JavaScript

```
$.getJSON("/Switch/LoadDataCenterByRack", { id: idRack },
function (response) {
    $("#Switch_TMSRack_DataCenter_Name").val(response.DCData.Text);
    $("#Switch_TMSRack_Zone_Name").val(response.ZData.Text);
});
```

You can check what response you are getting by using `console.log` in JavaScript like

```
console.log(response)
```